# Twitter scraping with python

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I'm trying to use the `twitter 1.17.1` for Python 3.5 and I want to know what are and where do I get the following parameters data to pass as a parameter in the following function:

```
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(
auth=OAuth(token, token_key, con_secret, con_secret_key))
```

the token is the user id? the token_key is the password?  and the con_secret, and the con_secret_key ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of API token. [Please have a look here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-owner-access-tokens).